# How to keep the name of vector as a column in the tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I have the following list of named vectors:

```
lof <- list(PP1 = c(A = -0.96, R = 0.8, N = 0.82, D = 1, C = -0.55, 
E = 0.94, Q = 0.78, G = -0.88, H = 0.67, I = -0.94, L = -0.9, 
K = 0.6, M = -0.82, F = -0.85, P = -0.81, S = 0.41, T = 0.4, 
W = 0.06, Y = 0.31, V = -1), PP2 = c(A = -0.76, R = 0.63, N = -0.57, 
D = -0.89, C = -0.47, E = -0.54, Q = -0.3, G = -1, H = -0.11, 
I = -0.05, L = 0.03, K = 0.1, M = 0.03, F = 0.48, P = -0.4, S = -0.82, 
T = -0.64, W = 1, Y = 0.42, V = -0.43), PP3 = c(A = 0.31, R = 0.99, 
N = 0.02, D = -1, C = 0.19, E = -0.99, Q = -0.38, G = 0.49, H = 0.37, 
I = -0.18, L = -0.24, K = 1, M = -0.08, F = -0.58, P = -0.07, 
S = 0.57, T = 0.37, W = -0.47, Y = -0.2, V = -0.14))
```

What I want to do is to convert it to tibble and keeping the name of the vector as a column in a tibble.

With this:

```
library(tidyverse)
as_tibble(lof)
```

I get this:

```
# A tibble: 20 × 3
     PP1   PP2   PP3
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 -0.96 -0.76  0.31
 2  0.8   0.63  0.99

 .. etc ...
```

What I want to get is this:

```
     PP1   PP2   PP3. residue
 1 -0.96 -0.76  0.31   A
 2  0.8   0.63  0.99   R
  .. etc ...
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `data.table::transpose(bind_rows(lof, .id = 'row'),make.names = 'row', keep.names = 'residue')`??

Comment: onyambu's idea, but more compact - `bind_rows(purrr::transpose(lof), .id = "residue")`.

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to add a new column named "residue":

```
as_tibble(lof) %>%
  mutate(residue = names(lof[[1]]))


# A tibble: 20 × 4
     PP1   PP2   PP3 residue
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
 1 -0.96 -0.76  0.31 A      
 2  0.8   0.63  0.99 R      
 3  0.82 -0.57  0.02 N      
 4  1    -0.89 -1    D      
 5 -0.55 -0.47  0.19 C      
 6  0.94 -0.54 -0.99 E      
 7  0.78 -0.3  -0.38 Q      
 8 -0.88 -1     0.49 G      
 9  0.67 -0.11  0.37 H      
10 -0.94 -0.05 -0.18 I      
11 -0.9   0.03 -0.24 L      
12  0.6   0.1   1    K      
13 -0.82  0.03 -0.08 M      
14 -0.85  0.48 -0.58 F      
15 -0.81 -0.4  -0.07 P      
16  0.41 -0.82  0.57 S      
17  0.4  -0.64  0.37 T      
18  0.06  1    -0.47 W      
19  0.31  0.42 -0.2  Y      
20 -1    -0.43 -0.14 V
```

or

```
lof_new <- as_tibble(lof)
lof_new$residue <- names(lof[[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer works however if your names are not in order in all of the list items or they are of different lengths, you could also use the below.

```
library(tidyverse)
lof %>% 
  map(~tibble(name = names(.x), value=.x)) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "ID") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = value, values_fill = NA)
```

```
# A tibble: 20 x 4
   name    PP1   PP2   PP3
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A     -0.96 -0.76  0.31
 2 R      0.8   0.63  0.99
 3 N      0.82 -0.57  0.02
 4 D      1    -0.89 -1   
 5 C     -0.55 -0.47  0.19
 6 E      0.94 -0.54 -0.99
 7 Q      0.78 -0.3  -0.38
 8 G     -0.88 -1     0.49
 9 H      0.67 -0.11  0.37
10 I     -0.94 -0.05 -0.18
11 L     -0.9   0.03 -0.24
12 K      0.6   0.1   1   
13 M     -0.82  0.03 -0.08
14 F     -0.85  0.48 -0.58
15 P     -0.81 -0.4  -0.07
16 S      0.41 -0.82  0.57
17 T      0.4  -0.64  0.37
18 W      0.06  1    -0.47
19 Y      0.31  0.42 -0.2 
20 V     -1    -0.43 -0.14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bind_cols(lof, residue=names(lof$PP1))
```